# perf top : failed to mmap with 22 (invalid argument)

Tags: perf

How to use --mmap-pages option from perf-top ?

This is **not** working :

```
~> perf top --stdio -K -e cpu-clock:u,cache-misses:u -p 1234
Error:
Failed to mmap with 22 (Invalid argument)
```

But, all of these are working **OK** :

```
~> perf top --stdio -K -e cpu-clock:u,cache-misses:u
...

~> perf top --stdio -K -e cpu-clock:u -p 1234
...

~> perf top --stdio -K -e cpu-clock:u
...

~> perf top --stdio -K -e cache-misses:u
...

~> perf top --stdio -K -e cache-misses:u -p 1234
...
```

FGH

PS : I am running debian

```
~> uname -r
4.6.0-1-amd64
```

**UPDATE**

```
~> cat /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid
-1
~> more /etc/sysctl.conf | grep paranoid
kernel.perf_event_paranoid = -1
```

**UPDATE**

For the record, I guess perf-top can handle only **one** event :

```
~> man perf-top
       -e <event>, --event=<event>
           Select the PMU event.
                  ---
```

Comment: have you tried to look at /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid ?

Comment: yes, perf-stat and perf-record run OK : see the update